# How to pass output to Ping as stdin

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have this command to strip the https:// portion and truncate the ending /.

```sh
echo https://example.com/ | awk -F '//' {'print $2'} | tr -d '/'
```

How can I pass the output to ping or host command as a stdin, making it an oneliner?

```
example.com
```

The expected output is the result of host/ping example.com
I have tried below commands

```sh
echo https://example.com/ | awk -F '//' {'print $2'} | tr -d '/' | ping $ 
echo https://example.com/ | awk -F '//' {'print $2'} | tr -d '/' | ping $1
```

I never got the expected results.

Comment: I think you're looking for `xargs`

Comment: Instead of the `awk | tr` thing, how about `sed 's@.*://@@; s@/.*@@'`? Explanation: the `s@.*://@@` deleted from the beginning through "://", then `s@/.*@@` deletes from the slash (the first, if there are several) through the end. That'll make it work even if there's more to the URL than just the domain name.

Comment: I have already answered the question, @oguzismail - That what I have done, kindly look the answer,

Comment: @GordonDavisson - that was a nice thought,I was doing awk and tr for my other engagements processing the domains, your suggestion is indeed a valuable one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it can be achieved by piping using xargs

```sh
echo https://example.com/ | awk -F '//' {'print $2'} | tr -d '/' | xargs ping 

echo https://example.com/ | awk -F '//' {'print $2'} | tr -d '/' | xargs host
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
echo https://example.com/ |(IFS=/ read http nothing host; ping $host)
```

IFS splits the reading at the slash character; the parenthesis are needed for *read* to work. If you just need the ping the above command is ok. Or, you can extract the host name:

```
host=$(echo https://example.com/ |(IFS=/ read http nothing host; echo $host))
ping $host
```